# Visual studio code debugging console error: "...botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.SSLError EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777) "

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, boto3

I have this strange issue while running a simple boto3 script from visual code. I'm behind corporate proxy and when I run my proxy script followed by my boto3 script from terminal, it works fine.

However, when I run this from Code, I get this annoying exception at line 16 "Exception has occurred: botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.SSLError EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:777)".

So, as a work around, I ran the proxy script again followed by the same python boto3 script from "terminal within Code" and it ran fine. But, immediately after this when I ran the same script (it's idempotent) thru debugger, I get the same exception. Attaching the screen shot.

I have installed python from conda and set up python path in CODE accordingly.
[image]